# Not seeing hand in rviz during kinect skeleton demo

Tags: kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to work with mit's kinect demos , everything is comiled and running - the prime sense viewer works brilliantly tracking person's skeleton but I am not able to visualize the hand point cloud data in the rviz - /hand0_point2 and all other topic are not working as I executed ' rostopic hz /hand0_point2 ' and the terminal shows only 'suscribed to /hand0_point2 and nothing shows up after that.

- in the rviz i am not able to see my skeleton and no hand point cloud .
- the status of the topics in the rviz shows warning with yellow glow at the status

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11265/not-seeing-hand-in-rviz-during-kinect-skeleton-demo/) by [Robin Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1045/robin-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz will usually give you a more specific error when you expand the yellow status. That will usually give you a clue as to what it has a problem with.

---

Originally posted by [akargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/1025/akargol/) with karma: 126 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2